# how to create a transparent UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, transparency, uibarbuttonitem, transparent, tint

I have a UINavigationBar with a pattern on it. I've seen a lot of UI that implement transparent UIBarButtonItem, and I wonder how to make the same.

Tint dosent do the trick unfortunately...

please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a UIButton inside the UIBarButton item. The button can be transparent. In Xcode's Interface Builder, just drag a UIButton to one of the empty corners of the UINavigationBar. Xcode will automatically create a UIBarButtonItem and put the UIButton inside it. You can then set the UIButton type to Custom and apply other properties such as title or image.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the procedure described by Melsam and set the transparency of the button by using

button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];